# Can I move users from one ASP .Net membership database to another with different Application ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is it possible to move users from one ASP .Net membership database to another with a different Application ID?  Both systems used passwordformat = hashed.  Only about 100 user accounts will be moved into the other database which contains about 20,000 accounts.  Usernames are unique.  If the 100 users need to reset their password that would be fine.

If possible my plan was to create insert statements to the aspnet_Membership and aspnet_Users tables possibly changing ApplicationID to the destination value prior to inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the details over with a new applicationId.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar once,

i made an asp.net page and put a code similar to this on a button click:

```
protected void Button_addMedicacao0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
String strConnection1 = "conectionstring1";
String strConnection2 = "conectionstring2";
try
{
    OleDbConnection dbConn = null;
    OleDbCommand dbCmd = null;
    OleDbDataReader dr = null;
    String strSQL = null;
    dbConn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection1);
    dbConn.Open();
    strSQL = "select * from TABLE1";
    dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbConn);
    dr = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbConnection dbConn2 = null;
                OleDbCommand dbCmd2 = null;
                String strSQL2 = null;
                dbConn2 = new OleDbConnection(strConnection2);
                dbConn2.Open();
                strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLE2 (Field1, Field2) VALUES (?, ?)";
                dbCmd2 = new OleDbCommand(strSQL2, dbConn2);
                // dr[0] = id_table1
                dbCmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Field1", dr[1].ToString()));
                dbCmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Field2", dr[2].ToString()));                       
                dbCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbConn2.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            { 
            }
        }
    }
    dbConn.Close();
}
catch (Exception err)
{  
}
}
```